# how to use yari in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, debugging, eclipse-rcp

I've downloaded and installed [yari](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/yet-another-rcp-inspector) but I cannot figure out how to use it. Everything I see is another menu item "YARI" with a couple of subitems but they all are pretty unclear. I haven't found any tutorial or documentation on this subject.

What I expect: some window which will automatically appear at a start and contain information about GUI of my application

What I get: nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the yari project is hosted on SourceForge:
https://sourceforge.net/p/yari/doc/Home/

On the "General" documentation page is an introduction to the yari toolsuite:
https://sourceforge.net/p/yari/doc/HowToGeneral/

To get access to the yari features you have to open the "Show view" dialog in your Eclipse and select there the yari tool you need (placed in the yari group). The main menu entries offer other yari-stuff.